# Qt QGraphicsView - tooltips don't appear

Tags: python, pyqt, tooltip, qgraphicsview

I'm creating a 2D view in PyQt using the QGraphicsView.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any way of getting tooltips to appear at any level - on QGraphicsItems, QGraphicsItemGroups, etc.

It's getting to the point where they'd be very useful, but I have tried:

1. Setting the tooltips using setToolTip().
2. Using setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AlwaysShowToolTips) on the QGraphicsView

The second I thought would be a dead-cert, but appears to do nothing at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work as expected using python Qt 4.8.7 with PyQt 4.11.4:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
        self.view.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self))
        for index, name in enumerate('One Two Three Four Five'.split()):
            item = QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem(index * 60, index * 60, 50, 50)
            item.setToolTip('Rectangle: ' + name)
            self.view.scene().addItem(item)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(400, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Presumably, there must be something different in your own code that is compromising the normal behaviour. But that will be impossible to identify without a proper test case.

Comment: Thanks, @ekhumoro - your nice simple test case does indeed work for me, so it is something I am doing *somewhere*.  I'll post what it is once I find it (it's not obvious - I believe that I am doing (in essence) what you've done above)...

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to @ekhumoro prompting me to take a more logical approach to the problem, I've identified the problem.

The problem was due to the inheritance structure, and my overenthusiastic attempts to reduce code duplication.  I've distilled it into an (non)working example, which looks a bit more stupid than the original code (or maybe just reveals the stupidity):

```py
    from PyQt4 import QtGui
    
    class MyRect(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem, QtGui.QGraphicsItem):
        def __init__(self, index):
            QtGui.QGraphicsItem.__init__(self, )
            self.setToolTip('Rectangle: '+str(index))    # <-- This doesn't work
            QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, index * 60, index * 60, 50, 50)
            #self.setToolTip('Rectangle: '+str(index))     <-- This works
    
    
    class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Window, self).__init__()
            self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self)
            self.view.setScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self))
            for index, name in enumerate('One Two Three Four Five'.split()):
                item = MyRect(index)
                #item.setToolTip('Rectangle: ' + name)    # <-- This would work
                self.view.scene().addItem(item)
            layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
            layout.addWidget(self.view)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        import sys
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = Window()
        window.resize(400, 400)
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The original effort was to try to extract all of the mundanities - such as setting tooltips and context menus - into an abstract class inheriting from QGraphicsItem.  However, this meant that you called the QGraphicsItem's constructor twice, and setToolTip needs to be called after *both* of the constructors.

Needless to say, I'm refactoring the code to remove the duplicate inheritance of QGraphicsItem...